# I am speaking a line at a time from a text file in a vb program, How do I read one line at a time?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a text reader that reads one line at a time.  How do I do this in Vb 2008 express?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do and include code examples of what you've tried. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) (a good question)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at the System.IO namespace for the [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function it will return an `IEnumerable(Of String)` which you can then iterate through.

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String) = File.ReadLines("Your File Path Here")
        For Each line As String In lines
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I pasted the code in my question.  don't know why it doesn't show but here it is again.

Comment: @Barryal Don't see it in your question, time stamp says last edited Oct 22 2013, try it again. Are you still experiencing the problem 3 years later ?